# CSS: Dropdown menu being hidden by container's overflow property

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am editing a large project with a lot of existing code so I am unable to change the table structure's HTML but I can do change the CSS.
A lot of the content is long and the intention is the make the `.container` scrollable from left to right if the content overflow.
In the codepen below, if you change the `.container`'s `overflow-x` property to `auto` or `scroll`, which I want it to do, the dropdown menu that is triggered by the CLICK ME link only displays what is inside the container and clips anything outside of that.  Is there anyway to bypass this?

https://codepen.io/lorvenji95/pen/ExaGePz

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}
.container {
  margin-top:100px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:grey;
  overflow-x: inherit;
  max-height: 150px;
}


td {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.foo {
  color: red;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  right:20px;
  top:-30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2147483549;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td .dropdown-menu {
  top: -30px !important;
}

tr:nth-last-child(-n+2) td .dropdown-menu{
  top: -165px;
}
a.dropdown-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 20px;
}
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-bitbucket {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #163758;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <table>
     <td>
      Option1
    </td>
     <td class="foo">
      CLICK
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="options" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            .....
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="options">
            <li><a href="/admin/orders" class="link">Associated Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/items" class="link">Associated Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/colors" class="link">Associated Colors</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/waitlist/by-customer" class="link">Associated Lists</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/shopping-cart" class="link">Associated Carts</a></li>      
            <li><a href="/admin/waitlist/others" class="link">Others</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/waitlist/account" class="link">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
     <td>
      Option3
    </td>
     <td>
      Option4
    </td>
    <td>
      Option5
    </td>
     <td>
      Option6
    </td>
    <td>
      Option7
    </td>
     <td>
     Option8
    </td>
     <td>
     Optio9
    </td>
     <td>
      Option10
    </td>
    <td>
      Option11
    </td>
     <td>
      Option12
    </td>
    <td>
      Option13
    </td>
     <td>
      Option14
    </td>    
  </table>
  
</div>
```

[image: dropdown cut off]

Comment: So what you want is the select option list the rest of the hidden content in the div dynamically depending on screen size. Am i right?

Comment: Please try: `transform: none;` on '.dropdown-menu' class

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know exactly what you are asking for I made a solution to is don't know it solves your problems please change this below css and try. Thanks and sorry if did't work as u expected.

```
.container {
  margin-top:100px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:grey;
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-height: 150px;
}
td {
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu{
  right:20px;
  top:0;
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 2147483549;
  transform: none !important;
}
```